# Быстрое создание DOM объектов в JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Есть функция, которая вставляет сообщение в чат:

```
    var date = new Date(m.time);
    var username = $("<span class='username'>" + m.username + ": </span>");
    var text = $("<span class='text'>" + m.text + "</span>");
    var nameText = $("<td class='name_text'></td>");
    nameText.append(username);
    nameText.append(text);
    var time = $("<td class='time'>" + formatDate(date) + "</td>");
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    tr.append(nameText);
    tr.append(time);
    var message = $("<table class='message'></table>");
    message.append(tr);

    var chat = $("#chat");
    chat.append(message);
```

Очевидно, что она достаточно "тяжёлая", тратит много ресурсов. Как по-другому вставить сообщение в чат? Возможно, иметь заранее созданный объект заготовку, чтобы копировать его и просто заменять текст? Или лучше будет генерировать всё это одной строкой типа

```
function getMessageHTML(m) {
    return "<table class='message'><tr><td class='text'>"+m.text+"</td></tr></table>";
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не может ответить? Ну и ладно, по традиции отвечу сам себе.

[Вот отличная статья](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly/), которая советует делать вот так:

```
var arr = reallyLongArray;
var textToInsert = [];
var i = 0;
var length = arr.length;
for (var a = 0; a <length; a += 1) {
    textToInsert[i++]  = '<tr><td name="pieTD">';
    textToInsert[i++] = arr[a];
    textToInsert[i++] = '</td> </tr>' ;

}
$('table').append(textToInsert.join(''));
```

Вместо того, чтобы делать вот так:

```
var arr = reallyLongArray;
$.each(arr, function(count, item) {
    var newTd = $('<td></td>').html(item).attr('name','pieTD');
    var newTr = $('<tr></tr>');
    newTr.append(newTd);
    $('table').append(newTr);
});
```

Comment: вызовы `textToInsert[i++] ...` можно заменить на `textToInsert.push('<tr><td name="pieTD">'); textToInsert.push(arr[a]); ...`